# Cannot add row to spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

```
var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.open('Student Files Data').getId();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssNew);

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
sheet.appendRow(["a man", "a plan", "panama"]);
```

I can't seem to get this to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the first line; the open() method expects a file object, not the file name as a string. Use the DriveApp [getFilesByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByName(String)) method, which will return a file iterator, and next() will return the first match.

```
var ssNew = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Student Files Data").next().getId;
```